# elastic search table in hive not returning any ouput

Tags: elasticsearch, hive, kibana

We have some log data on elastic search on index "logstash*",

We created hive external table using above index .But when we query ,its not showing any data.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tablename (
id    string,
name  string,
data string)
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES('es.net.http.auth.user'= 'xxx', 'es.net.http.auth.pass'= 'xxx' , 
'es.net.ssl'= 'true', 'es.nodes' = 'xxxa5:9200', 'es.resource' = 'logstash*',
'es.index.auto.create' = 'false', 'es.query' = '?q=*');

hive> select * from tablename limit 10;
OK
Time taken: 0.676 seconds
```

But when i query ,it is not showing anything. I dont see any errors in hive too.

Elastic search version "5.6.10",I am using this connector elasticsearch-hadoop-hive-5.6.10.jar;

Comment: Not all details provided. I think your table is empty because you didn't explicitly provide location of already existed data (see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable "LOCATION hdfs_path"). So either specify LOCATION or import data into created table.

Comment: when you create hive table on elastic search index you dont specify location